# How can I add server field to post on data in PHP?

Tags: wordpress

Welcome to use the WordPress template developer allows the addition of servers to watch movies I have some problems are when you add a server and update the article is updated but returns the right empty or not added and then when you delete the server is not deleted I checked the error record and this is the result

[21-Sep-2018 10:42:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154

File functions.php

https://3bdo.info/functions.zip

Comment: Any chance you can add "line 154" and any relevant code?

Comment: This File functions.php

https://3bdo.info/functions.zip

Comment: File wont unzip.

Comment: Do you want any other files from the template?

Comment: oh its not a zip file its a php file

Comment: You can not post new topics in this forum https://3bdo.info/functions.txt

Comment: Whats the output of this: Add the following to line 308: `var_dump($android_servers_title2);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($android_servers_code2);`

Comment: I am grateful to you, if you add the code yourself

Comment: I can't. The functions in there are not valid you need to run it.

Comment: Thank now The Android Server  field works well and the deletion also works

Comment: But the Android servers Dblga field does not work as well as the deletion does not work

Comment: After the addition of the code var_dump($android_servers_title2); echo "<br>"; var_dump($android_servers_code2);   to line 308, the addition of the server is already running, but the deletion does not work in all fields

Comment: Last error [21-Sep-2018 12:14:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154
[21-Sep-2018 12:15:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154
[21-Sep-2018 12:17:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154

Answer (score 1):

The linked zip file seams to be broken so I cannot extract the file.

But in general the error message says, that you have to use two arrays to call array_combine. You seam to try to combine an array (which is like a list) and a boolean (which is like yes/no). And that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$android_servers_title2 = servers_get_meta( 'android_download_server_title' );
$android_servers_code2 = servers_get_meta( 'android_download_server_link' );
/* foreach($servers_title as $server_title)
   {
     echo "<label for='servers_server_title'>Server Title</label>";
     echo " <br><input type='text' name='servers_server_title[]' id='servers_server_title' value='" . $server_title . "'><br>";
   } */

if($android_servers_title2){
    $android_arraye2 = array_combine($android_servers_title2, $android_servers_code2);
}else {
    $android_arraye2 = false;
}
```

This is basically your problem. servers_get_meta is returning 'false' I would imagine. Check that 'android_download_server_link' is set. you may wish to change the if statement code to detect a false

```
if($android_servers_title2 && $android_servers_code2){
```

Comment: p.s. difficult to know what the issue is without knowing what servers_get_meta() actually does!

Comment: When you add server fields that work but the deletion does not work, when you click the field buttons in the Modify Servers page and then the article is updated and not deleted

Comment: Last error [21-Sep-2018 12:14:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154
[21-Sep-2018 12:15:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154
[21-Sep-2018 12:17:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home3/oktooonc/public_html/wp-content/themes/movie/functions.php on line 154

Comment: This still looks like you are having issues with an item returning false. Can you post a dump of $android_servers_title2 and $android_servers_code2?